# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32 for DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, datagridview, int32

I have a C# form linked to an SQL database, and for one of the columns I wish to insert the current date each time a new row is added. I am baffled because at one point this code was doing exactly what I wanted, and then after changing a few things it now keeps throwing the error "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32." and I don't know what happened.
Here is my table definition. I know the value types are probably a bit arbitrary, but all I care about is that the date is stored as a string.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InvTable] (
[ID]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Item]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[QuantRem] INT           NULL,
[Type]     NCHAR (10)    NULL,
[DateOrd]  NCHAR(10)    NULL,
[QuantOrd] INT           NULL,
[Received] BIT           NULL,
[DateRec]  NCHAR(10)    NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

And the code on the form is below. The second date will be defined differently later, but my primary concern is getting rid of the error in the title.

```
    private void Submitbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Submit Empty Request");
            return;
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Use Drop Down Menu To Select Item Category");
            return;
        }
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO InvTable VALUES(@Item, @QuantRem, @Type, @DateReq, @QuantOrd, @Received, @DateRec)", con);
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Item", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@QuantRem", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox2.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateReq", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("d");
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@QuantOrd", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Received", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateRec", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("d");
        con.Open();
        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM InvTable WHERE Received=0", con);
        con.Close();
        ds.Clear();
        da.Fill(ds);
        invTableDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        textBox1.Clear();
    }
```

So this code used to work at one point, giving me a string "07/20/2015", but now it just gives me an error.

Comment: Why are you using text to represent a date at all? You should use a `Date` field in the database if you *possibly* can. As for the problem in your question - I suggest you explicitly do the parsing in your code, e.g. `int.Parse(textBox2.Text)`. I *suspect* that's where the problem is, but you should be able to work that out.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the QuantRem **int** value being converted from textBox2. **text** that's the issue? The date **string** isn't undergoing any conversion at any point

Comment: It was just for the purpose of logging when it was done... no real data function. Would using the Date field fix the problem?

Comment: i think field is wrong typed in your code [DateOrd] as ("@DateReq",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are a victim of [choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).

Change your `DateOrd` and `DateRec` column types to [`date` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) and pass your `DateTime.Today` directly to your parameterized query (since you keep only date part of a `DateTime`).

```
[DateOrd]  date    NULL,
...
...
[DateRec]  date   NULL,
```

and

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateReq", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateRec", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today;
```

Also for `QuantRem` column, looks like you need to parse `textBox2.Text` value to int before you pass it as a parameter.

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@QuantRem", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
```

Don't forget to use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections, commands and adapters automatically instead of calling `Close` methods manually.

Comment: QuantRem was definitely the problem. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, don't use text when you could/should be using an actual `date` type ... it will save you a lot of hassle now and in the future.

But your actual error is more likely to be this line:
`da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@QuantRem", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox2.Text;`

Where you are taking text and trying to set an integer parameter. Convert that text to an integer, and then set your integer parameter.

Comment: Yup QuantRem was the problem. +1